# getElementsByTagName equivalent?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I use `cocoonjs` to make `HTML5` game on Android, but I can't use `requirejs` cause of the method `getElementsByTagName` which doesn't work, anybody has an idea how I can replace that :

```
document.getElementsByTagName('script');
```

Comment: getElementsByTagName should work fine?!

Comment: Not according to this feature list - however it may not be 100% complete - http://wiki.ludei.com/cocoonjs:featurelist#document -- rather strange thing for them not to support.

Comment: What does `console.log(typeof document.getElementsByTagName)` report?

Comment: I've used already require.js on an Android WebView, so it must surely work

Comment: @pebbl The wiki is a bit deprecated indeed
Actually the getElementsByTagName seems to work since the last update, after many tests I found the problem : the "script" tag hasn't "onload" implementation, that's why requirejs doesnt work...

Answer (score 0):

So my problem has actually no link with the `getElementsByTagName` function, but for those who want an equivalent I have this one :

```
var scriptArray = [];
for (var s in document.head.childNodes)
{
  if (document.head.childNodes[s].nodeName == "SCRIPT")
  {
    scriptArray.push(document.head.childNodes[i]);
  }
}
```